# setSelectedButton & setSelectedKey for segmented button

Tags: sapui5

hey guys not sure if this is a bug or theres something I'm doing wrong, or the CSS style sheets im using are making this error, but im racking my brain on how to fix this.

I have the following code bellow in a loop, ever since I put it in a loop it no longer works as setting the selected button I had a search and some one said try set selected key, I also tried this and no luck. Now I have put them both in and it sets the selected value to neither button. I'll show you screenshots of what I mean. Any ideas on fixing it would be great.

```
        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        //Create buttons dynamically
        var segmentItemYes = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"Yes", press: [this.onSEYesPress, this]});
        var segmentItemNo = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem({text :"No",  press: [this.onSENoPress, this]});
        var segmentedButton = new sap.m.SegmentedButton({items : [segmentItemYes, segmentItemNo]});

        //TODO:Doesn't work currently - How do we set default state?
        segmentedButton.setSelectedButton(segmentItemNo);
        segmentedButton.setSelectedKey(segmentItemNo);
```

Below is the Image the top part is what I'm getting (I clicked on no to show you what exactly happens. The bottom one is with the setSelectedKey removed but still set to no. any ideas? This is in a JS controller and it gets placed in to an xml fragment if this makes a difference or not.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work as follows, by binding the selected key to a model:

```
  var segmentItemYes = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem( {
      text: "Yes",
      key: "foo"
    });
    var segmentItemNo = new sap.m.SegmentedButtonItem( {
      text: "No",
      key: "bar"
    });
     var segmentedButton = new sap.m.SegmentedButton( {
      items: [segmentItemYes, segmentItemNo],
      selectedKey: {
        path: "test>/key"
      }
    });

var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  key: "bar"
    });
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(model, "test");
```

Comment: Hey man the old segmented button is a no, although it does work fine and how I want it, we are trying to stay away from stuff thats deprecated. The code you provided returns the erro "has no method 'setSelectedButton'". Back to the drawing board :/ thanks for the help though :).

Comment: @J0rd4n500 I fixed the answer, it now works as it is supposed to (not with deprecated functionality but with the new API). Good luck with it